# Field value must be initialised

Tags: c++

Consider my class definition, which is a nested class of `Ring<T>`:

```
template<class T>
class Ring<T>::Iterator{
private:
    int i_pos;
    Ring<T> &value;
public:
    Iterator(int index, Ring<T> &other) :  i_pos(index){
        value = other;
    }
};
```

The constructor throws an error, that `value` must be initialised. So my guess, is that due to the fact that `Iterator` is inside the class `Ring`, we must first initialise the `Ring<T>` object before constructing its inner class `Iterator`, am I right?

```
Iterator(int index, Ring<T> &other) : value(other), i_pos(index){
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a big difference between *initializing* a variable, and just *assigning* to a variable.

What you're doing with

```
Iterator(int index, Ring<T> &other) : value(other), i_pos(index){
}
```

is *initializing* the variable `value` and `i_pos`.

When you do

```
Iterator(int index, Ring<T> &other) :  i_pos(index){
    value = other;
}
```

you initialize `i_pos` but you try to assign to the variable `value` inside the constructor function body (which is called once all construction and initialization is finished).

And as you should know, you can't assign to a reference. A reference *must* be initialized. This is because any access to a (initialized) reference performs the operation on the referenced data, what the reference variable references.

To elaborate, see this example code:

```
int a, b = 5;
int& r = a;  // Make r reference a

r = b;  // Assign the value of b to the variable a, equal to a = b
```